# C++ buffer overrun

Tags: c++, buffer-overrun

I'm learning C++ and whilst I have a reasonable understanding of C# I've never run into this issue before. With a simple program that places chess pieces on an imaginary board (an enumerated array) and then assigns the squares which would have pieces at the start their pieces, you are then asked for coordinates and the program returns what is on that square. It displays the correct piece yet will always crash in non-debugging mode and display a buffer overrun in Visual Studio debugging. It's quite short so I'll show all the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
enum Chessboard {
    Blank,
    Pawn,
    Rook,
    Knight,
    Bishop,
    King,
    Queen
};
Chessboard board[8][8] = { Blank };
for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++)
{
    board[1][x] = Pawn;
    board[8][x] = Pawn;
}
board[7][0] = Rook;
board[7][1] = Knight;
board[7][2] = Bishop;
board[7][3] = King;
board[7][4] = Queen;
board[7][5] = Bishop;
board[7][6] = Knight;
board[7][7] = Rook;
board[0][0] = Rook;
board[0][1] = Knight;
board[0][2] = Bishop;
board[0][4] = King;
board[0][3] = Queen;
board[0][5] = Bishop;
board[0][6] = Knight;
board[0][7] = Rook;

int X = 0;
int Y = 0;
bool Error = false;
cout << "Enter the coordinates of a square on a chessboard to see what is on there at    the start of the game (1 number at a time)" << endl;
do {
    cin >> X;
    X--;
    Error = false;
    if (X < 0 || X > 7)
    {
        cout << "That's not on the board" << endl;
        Error = true;
    }
} while (Error = false);
do {
    cin >> Y;
    Y--;
    Error = false;
    if (Y < 0 || Y > 7)
    {
        cout << "That's not on the board" << endl;
        Error = true;
    }
} while (Error = false);

string Name = "";
Chessboard Piece = board[X][Y];
switch (Piece)
{
case Blank: Name = "nothing";
    break;
case Pawn: Name = "a Pawn";
    break;
case Rook: Name = "a Rook";
    break;
case Knight: Name = "a Knight";
    break;
case Bishop: Name = "a Bishop";
    break;
case King: Name = "a King";
    break;
case Queen: Name = "a Queen";
    break;
default: Name = "Somehow you missed the board";
    break;
} 

cout << "On " << ++X << "," << ++Y << " there is " << Name << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the line `board[8][x]`. How many spaces did you allocate for board? in C++ arrays are indexed 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: `board[8][x] = Pawn;` is one too many (indexes are 0 - 7). I think you actually want `6`

Comment: BTW common wisdom in C++ is use vector rather than raw arrays. Vectors have .at member function which catches buffer overrun

Comment: You also failed you loop condition : while (Error = false) have to be while (Error == false) ; Error = false is always false

Comment: Surely if you do something similar in C# you get an exception?

Comment: I just spotted that thank you, I can't believe the rookie mistakes I'm making, it's not THAT different from C# I should be spotting these.

Comment: I probably would although despite using the same IDE, C#'s tends to be a little more informative and it usually catches that error in plain English.

Comment: @user3624136 In C++, a buffer overrun is not an error, so I don't know what diagnostic you are referring to. As for `while (foo = false)` this should probably trigger a diagnostic warning. If not, see about increasing the warning level of your compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll certainly get an overrun here:

```
Chessboard board[8][8] = { Blank };
for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++)
{
  board[1][x] = Pawn;
  board[8][x] = Pawn; 
}
```

There's no `board[8][]`. You have `board[0][]` through `board[7][]` available.

Comment: Ah perfect, I shrunk the board because chess boards are 8x8 not 10 by 10 and I missed that number, one day I'll get used to 0 indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You are going outside the boundaries of your matrix

```
   board[1][x] = Pawn;
   board[8][x] = Pawn;
```

You declared it 8x8 so index 0..7 are to be used.

Comment: I don't suppose you could explain why it gets down to the code where I can input and only crashes at the end? I can get accurate answers out of it so surely it should be crashing earlier? (I replaced the 8 with 7 and it works perfectly, I just don't know why it sort of worked earlier)

Comment: Because you overruned on the stack, destroying the stack frame, then the program crashes when it tries to unwinde it.

Comment: @user3624136 When you use native arrays like that there is no boundschecking in C++ you are basically writing to a part of memory that may be occupied by something else. In some cases you can get away with it and the program seems to work but sooner or later your luck will run out and it crashes, often in some other part of the program that accesses that piece of memory.

Answer (score 1):

In C, C++ and C# indices of arrays start from 0 to size of the array - 1. So for example this loop

```
for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++)
{
    board[1][x] = Pawn;
    board[8][x] = Pawn;
}
```

has to be rewritten as

```
for ( int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    board[1][x] = Pawn;
    board[6][x] = Pawn;
}
```

provided that the array is defined as

```
Chessboard board[8][8] = { Blank };
```

Also it would be a good idea to introduce a mnemonic name for magic number 8 and use this name everwhere instead of the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    board[0][x] = Pawn;
    board[7][x] = Pawn;
}
```

I think 7 is the maximum for this array.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by everybody else, its  the `board[8][x] = Pawn` that is causing the error.

Though this appears to be a test program rather than something that will go into production but still one word of caution that I would like to advise, always  try to avoid numbers / hard coded strings/integers or anything else, in your code for reason that you usually end up doing things like this. And one day when project goes into production and may be your boss will decide to change the value to say, 100 x 100, you will have a very hard time doing things.

Good Ways to do this :

```
static const int BoardSize = 10;
```

or

```
#define BoardSize 10;
```